# Set Some particluar word as BOLD and send this text as SMS using TWILIO[c#]

Tags: c#, twilio-api

I want to make  particular words as BOLD and send as SMS [with he help of twilio] in c#

Comment: SMS doesn't support formatting. Maybe you mean an MMS of some kind?

Comment: I have implemented a functionality to send sms from c# web api using Twilio. It is running successfully now.Using string builder, i create the body of the message.Now i want a functionality to include some words are bold in the message.So using html tags, i have format the message.But it didn't affect when the sms comes on the mobile[nexus 5].So is there any solution for this?

Comment: No, **SMS does not support formatting** of text, it's **plain text only**.